# Bind Settings to a group of RadioButtons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a kind of annoying scenario here.
In my WPF GUI I declared some RadioButtons, I want the right one to be checked when the GUI loads.

XAML:

```
<RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="RadioButtonShowSettings" GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Show settings window" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="RadioButtonOpenFile" GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Open upload dialog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Name="RadioButtonIndexFile" GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Open file indexer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="RadioButtonImageGallery" GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Open image gallery" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="RadioButtonTakeScreenshot" GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Take a screenshot (3 seconds delay)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

To keep possible bugs to a minimum I created a Property in my HonkySettings of the type String called TrayIconBehaviour. It contains the ContentProperty of the currently checked RadioButton.

I've been doing the loading programatically with a LoadSettings() function, but I'd like to remove that and do something more appealing with Bindings.

LoadSettings:

```
private void LoadSettings()
{
    List<RadioButton> TrayIconBehaviourRadioButtons = GridTrayIconBehaviour.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList();
    foreach (RadioButton rButton in TrayIconBehaviourRadioButtons)
    {
        if (rButton.Content.Equals(HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour))
            rButton.IsChecked = true;
    }

    List<RadioButton> FullscreenCaptureRadioButtons = GridFullscreenCapture.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList();
    foreach (RadioButton rButton in FullscreenCaptureRadioButtons)
    {
        if (rButton.Content.Equals(HonkySettings.Default.FullscreenCapture))
            rButton.IsChecked = true;
    }

    if (RadioButtonQualityPNG.Content.Equals(HonkySettings.Default.ScreenCaptureQuality))
        RadioButtonQualityPNG.IsChecked = true;
    else RadioButtonQualityJPG.IsChecked = true;
}
```

I've got HonkyGuiControls, which contains WPF User Controls that I use in my HonkySettingsWindow, if needed, I'd be ready to create a custom RadioButton to bind my settings to them.

I already tried to create a User Control called CustomRadioButton and bind its IsCheckedProperty to something like this:

```
public Boolean IsChecked
{
    get
    {
        if (CustomRadioButton.Content.Equals(HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    set
    {
        HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour = CustomRadioButton.Content.ToString();
    }
}
```

But the CustomRadioButton IsChecked Property wouldn't bind to it, because I'd need to create a DependencyProperty, and I have no idea how I should do the same thing with a DependencyProperty. Help please.

Comment: Click the WPF GUI link in my description. Everything is linked.

Comment: We are unfortunately not here to review your source code. If you want help you'll need to provide us with a more specific example here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: okay added everything, should be clearer now. sorry for not doing that from the start.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to this using binding, try this

> xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stackoverflow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SettingsConverter x:Key="settingsConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Show settings window">
        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}">
                <Binding Path="HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour"/>
                <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </RadioButton.IsChecked>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Open upload dialog">
        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}">
                <Binding Path="HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour"/>
                <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </RadioButton.IsChecked>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Open file indexer">
        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}">
                <Binding Path="HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour"/>
                <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </RadioButton.IsChecked>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Open image gallery">
        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}">
                <Binding Path="HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour"/>
                <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </RadioButton.IsChecked>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Take a screenshot (3 seconds delay)">
        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}">
                <Binding Path="HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour"/>
                <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </RadioButton.IsChecked>
    </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

> Converter

```
    public class SettingsConverter:IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Count() == 2)
            return values.First() == values.Last();
        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

if you making alot of this kind of binding as i can see there so to reduce xaml code we can do it this way as below

> xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stackoverflow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Show settings window" IsChecked="{local:RadioButtonBinding HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour}"/>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Open upload dialog" IsChecked="{local:RadioButtonBinding HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour}"/>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Open file indexer"  IsChecked="{local:RadioButtonBinding HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour}"/>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Open image gallery"  IsChecked="{local:RadioButtonBinding HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour}"/>
    <RadioButton   GroupName="OnTrayClick" Content="Take a screenshot (3 seconds delay)" IsChecked="{local:RadioButtonBinding HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

> RadioButtonBinding

```
    public class RadioButtonBinding : MultiBinding
{
    public RadioButtonBinding(string propName)
    { 
        Bindings.Add(new Binding(propName));
        Bindings.Add(new Binding("Content") { RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self) });
        Converter = new SettingsConverter();
    }
}
```

> converter

```
    public class SettingsConverter:IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Count() == 2)
            return values.First() == values.Last();
        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried both ways now, but they don't work. I had to change up the RadioButtonBinding function a little, because I can't just write "HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour" as an argument in XAML. I removed the argument on the RadioButtonBinding constructor and added the HonkySettings.Default.TrayIconBehaviour setting directly to the first new Binding().

Comment: Using this way makes it impossible to convert back the content values when the RadioButton is pressed, since the value in the ConvertBack function is a Boolean.